# Why MySQL indexing is taking too much time for < operator?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

This  is my  MYSQL  table  **demo** having  more  than 7 million rows;

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | varchar(42)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| date  | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| text  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I read that indexes work sequentially.

**Case 1:**

```
 select  * from demo  where id="43984a7e-edcf-11ea-92c7-509a4cb89342" order by date limit 30;
```

I created  (id, date) index and it is working fine and query is executing too fast.

But  Hold on to see the below cases.

**Case 2:**

Below is my  SQL  query.

```
 select  * from demo  where id>"43984a7e-edcf-11ea-92c7-509a4cb89342" order by date  desc limit 30;
```

to execute the above query faster  I  created an index on (id, date). But it is taking more than 10 sec.
then I  made another index on (date). This took less than 1 sec. Why the composite index(id, date) is too much slower than (date)  index in this case ??

**Case 3:**

```
 select  * from demo  where id<"43984a7e-edcf-11ea-92c7-509a4cb89342" order by date  desc limit 30;
```

for this query, even the (date) index is taking more than  1.8 sec. Why  < operator is not optimized with any index either it is  (date) or(id, date).
and even this query is just going through around 300 rows and still taking more than 1.8 sec why?

```
mysql> explain select  * from demo  where id<"43984a7e-edcf-11ea-92c7-509a4cb89342" order by date  desc limit 30;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys         | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | demo  | NULL       | index | demoindex1,demoindex2 | demoindex3 | 6       | NULL |  323 |    36.30 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Any suggestions for how to create an index in  **Case 3**  to optimize it?

Comment: Just to observe that, by convention, any column called `id` tends to be defined as a surrogate, auto-incrementing PK.

Comment: it is using UUID() of MySQL.

Comment: But then date wouldn't be part of it.

Comment: GUIDs are *very bad keys* as the values are not just random by definition but unordered as well. Using just `UUID()` generates values that result in insertions all over the table, resulting in a *lot* of fragmentation. At the very least use a function that generates sequential GUIDs

Comment: And as Gordon writes, that composite key can't be used as an index for sorting. You should use only `id` as a primary key and index `date` separately.

Comment: What do you suggest for a unique id  which is reliable and good for indexing as well ??

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  We don't  know, for example, whether `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`.  This may make a significant difference in performance.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - MySQL almost never uses two separate indexes.  It will pick one or the other index and use it as much as it can, and not make any use of other indexes.

Comment: If `id` is known to be unique, the first query does not make sense -- there won't be more than one row.  So no need for the order by or limit.

Comment: Because of the random distribution of UUIDs, `"4398...` is about 26% of the way through the table.  That is "id>..." will need to go through more rows than "id<...".

Comment: Hey, Rick Id is not needed to be unique. It is just testing  to check performance. There is no constraint on any row.

Comment: My rant against UUIDs is here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid

Comment: @RickJames I knew MySQL's query optimizer was bad, but I still can't believe it's that bad. Any chance this was fixed in MySQL 8?

Comment: 8.0 provides the function that I suggest in my blog; but that is all.

Comment: Have you tried (date, id) index ? it could be used by the optimizer for the `order`, and the `where` clause I think. If you are only doing this to test the possible indexes.

Comment: Yeah ( date) or  (date, id) both indexes are working efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first query, the index can be used for both the `where` clause and the ordering.  So it will be very fast.

For the second query, the index can only be used for the `where` clause.  Because of the inequality, information about the `date` is no longer in order.  So the engine needs to explicitly order.

In addition, I imagine that the second query returns much more data than the first -- a fair amount of data if it take 10 seconds to sort it.